# Student’s t distribution counterpart for non-normally distributed outcomes

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

We apply the student’s t instead of the normal when we are estimating the standard deviation too (for example in a t-test).
But what happens with other probability distributions when we do a hypothesis test? Say for example we are using a Cauchy distribution with all its parameters being estimated.

Comment: It will be different for each distribution, so you're in for an infinitely long list. What estimators are you using for the Cauchy one?

Comment: @Glen_b just curious in general.

Comment: I guess you want a one-sample t-test under H0 (also covers the paired case). If you're mostly interested in shape rather than explicit algebra, simulation is easy. Here's what it looks like for a Cauchy with n=10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3bRW.png  The plot looks very similar for n=100. [Why does it have those two big modes? Because you're likely to get one extremely large outlier, much larger than the next biggest on either side of the center, $\mu$, which will make $s/\sqrt{n}$ and $\bar{x}-\mu$ similarly large (but $\bar{x}-\mu$ will be of random sign), leading to peaks near $\pm 1$.]

Comment: An exponential parent population produces a left-skewed t-statistic (the lack of large tail on the right is largely due to $s/\sqrt{n}$ being close in size to $\bar{x}-\mu$ when there's a big observation, pulling the right tail down). Many distributions that have not-so-heavy tails that are not-very-skew will produce t-statistics that look symmetric and more or less Gaussian-ish / t-ish in shape, becoming more Gaussian-looking as n gets larger.